# C# Remote Powershell SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to run powershell commands on a remote sharepoint server from a c# console app.  This is the code I have so far.  It runs without errors but does nothing.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

server name, username password, and url were taken out

```
    public static string RunScript()
    {

       Runspace remoteRunspace = null;
       openRunspace("http://server/wsman",
            "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell",
            @"domain\user",
            "password",
            ref remoteRunspace);
       try
       {
           StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
           using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
           {

               powershell.Runspace = remoteRunspace;
               powershell.AddScript("Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell");
               powershell.AddScript("enable-SPFeature -identity \"2dfc204b-e9da-4c6c-8b4f-c2f7c593ad4e\" -url sharepointsite -Confirm:$False");
               powershell.Invoke();
               Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
               remoteRunspace.Close();
               foreach (PSObject obj in results)
               {
                   stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
               }
           }

           return stringBuilder.ToString();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {

           return "";

       }


     }

    public static void  openRunspace(string uri, string schema, string username, string livePass, ref Runspace remoteRunspace)
    {
        System.Security.SecureString password = new System.Security.SecureString();
        foreach (char c in livePass.ToCharArray())
        {
            password.AppendChar(c);
        }
        PSCredential psc = new PSCredential(username, password);
        WSManConnectionInfo rri = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(uri), schema, psc);
        rri.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
        rri.ProxyAuthentication = AuthenticationMechanism.Negotiate;
        remoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rri);
        remoteRunspace.Open();
    }
```

Comment: You have called the `Invoke` 2 times, why?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check if you have access to the SharePoint databases, to add snap-in correctly you need ShellAccess permission on Configuration database as I remember and farm admin rights. Possibly your script can't add snap-in, so cant do anything with SharePoint object model.